# Convert Decimal to Varchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a decimal column in a table defined as decimal(8,3). I would like to include this column in a `Select` statement, convert it to a `Varchar` and only display two decimal places. I can't seem to find the right combination of options to do this because everything I try still produces three decimal places.

Comment: why don't you start by showing what you have got so far?

Comment: An example of your data and especially what you want it to look like always helps. Nicholas included a right-aligned answer since you didn't show how to display the results (Waste of time?). Your goal is to get the best answer possible and not discourage those volunteering solutions.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
create table #work
(
  something decimal(8,3) not null 
)

insert #work values ( 0 )
insert #work values ( 12345.6789 )
insert #work values ( 3.1415926 )
insert #work values ( 45 )
insert #work values ( 9876.123456 )
insert #work values ( -12.5678 )

select convert(varchar,convert(decimal(8,2),something))
from #work
```

if you want it right-aligned, something like this should do you:

```
select str(something,8,2) from #work
```

Comment: Never plug a decimal into the `STR()` function. It will cast the decimal to a float and might come up with funky rounding differences.

Comment: Exceedingly unlikely when asking it to round to to 2 decimal places, but point taken.

Answer (score 37):

If you are using SQL Server 2012, 2014 or newer, use the Format Function instead:

```
select Format( decimalColumnName ,'FormatString','en-US' )
```

Review the [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213505.aspx) topic and .NET format syntax for how to define the format string.

An example for this question would be:

```
select Format( MyDecimalColumn ,'N','en-US' )
```

Comment: this is a great solution

Comment: Be careful with `FORMAT()`, because [FORMAT() is nice and all, but…](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but). Take a look at this [performance comparison chart](https://sqlperformance.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/format_not_nice_1.png).

Answer (score 32):

You might need to convert the `decimal` to `money` (or `decimal(8,2)`) to get that exact formatting. The `convert` method can take a third parameter that controls the formatting style:

```
convert(varchar, cast(price as money))       12345.67
convert(varchar, cast(price as money), 0)    12345.67
convert(varchar, cast(price as money), 1)    12,345.67
```

Answer (score 5):

I think `CAST(ROUND(yourColumn,2) as varchar)` should do the job.

But why do you want to do this presentational formatting in T-SQL?

Comment: Gee thanks, I never thought of that! Of course I tried that and I still get 3 decimal places.

Comment: @Hosea146 Wrote my first answer without reading your question properly.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help you

```
Cast(columnName as Numeric(10,2)) 
        or

Cast(@s as decimal(10,2))
```

I am not getting why you want to cast to varchar?.If you cast to varchar again convert back to decimail for  `two` decimal points

Comment: Strange, this answer was at the end of the page and only this one solved my issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help .

```
DECLARE  @emp_cond nvarchar(Max) =' ',@LOCATION_ID  NUMERIC(18,0)   
SET@LOCATION_ID=10110000000
IF CAST(@LOCATION_ID AS VARCHAR(18))<>' ' 
            BEGIN
                SELECT @emp_cond= @emp_cond + N' AND 
CM.STATIC_EMP_INFO.EMP_ID = ' ' '+  CAST(@LOCATION_ID AS VARCHAR(18))  +' ' ' '
           END
print  @emp_cond  
EXEC( @emp_cond)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the type is decimal(18,0) you need to do a double convert like so:

```
convert(varchar, convert(decimal, [Bill to Account Number] ))
```

Otherwise, if you just do convert(varchar) you will get scientific notation.