# SSAS dimension for products shows wrong price format

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, mdx

I have a product dimension in my SSAS Cube (SSAS 2016) with different price attributes like sales price and purchase price.
The data source is a MS SQL Table with each price column defined as numeric(28,12).
I tried different approches to format these columns as currency but failed.
The currency format is working fine on the measure groups but not on the product dimension.
The browser always shows values like ".320000000000" instead of "0,32".
I have no idea left please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format option in dimension designer is at least ignored by excel and ssrs.

As a workaround add in your dimension a string/nvarchar attribute, which is formatted according to your desired pattern. You could either manifest the attribute in your datawarehouse dimension table or generate it by using a view.

**Addition**: To format your string you could use the tsql `format` function (supported from sql server 2012 on) like in the following example:

```
SELECT FORMAT(qry.col, 'N2') AS convertedString FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(numeric(28,12), .320000000000) AS col
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(numeric(28,12), 1.1) AS col
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(numeric(28,12), 100) AS col
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(numeric(28,12), 1000) AS col
) AS qry
```

The nvarchar result looks like this:

```
0.32
1.10
100.00
1,000.00
```

Comment: Do you mean adding a column in the dsv and format it as a string ?
I tried it with a new named calculation in the dsv and cast it as money like
"cast(SalesPrice as money)" even that isn't working in the Visual Studio Browser.
Every format is working fine on the measure groups but not on dimension level.

Comment: Please try the expression from the second answer for your dsv column to cast to nvarchar or even the third with the format function and check your result in sql or by using browse data function of data source view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572169/convert-decimal-to-varchar-in-t-sql

Comment: FORMAT finally did the trick, I am not sure maybe there is a better approach but this

FORMAT(SalesPrice, 'N', 'de-de') as SalesPrice

shows me the result needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the format in the dimension designer.  The property lives in the source group, under `NameColumn`.

[image: SSAS Properties]

Comment: I tried to set the format to currency and #.##0,00;-#.##0,00 on the NameColumn and even on the KeyColumn ... it isn't working.
I guess i miss something else

Comment: Maybe not.  The clients that connect to SSAS (Excel etc) are not forced to implement all of the properties.  I've been looking for documentation you could refer to but have drawn a blank.  If SSAS is sending the value as .32 and the client is not checking/using the format field then you have no way to force it.  An alternative is to present the data to SSAS in a formatted string (I know, I know - but if this in a dim table this is reference data, rather than a measure to be summed).

Comment: I don't know if this helps but I'm browsing the dimension via Visual Studio 2015 right after I perform a full process.

Comment: As far as I know this answer is incorrect. I believe Chris' answer is right.

Comment: Hi @GregGalloway, you are right.  Chris provides the better approach.  My answer is dependent on the chosen client respecting the value held in this property.  Chris demonstrates an excellent way of working around the fact that support is optional, and not required.